# Switch Row/Column on a chartsheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl

I have a large Excel sheet with data. Due to several reasons, I have data that is structured in a transposed way:

| Histogram | bin 0 | bin 1 | bin 2 | bin 3 | bin 4 | bin 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test 1 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| test 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 7 | 2 | 0 |

When I plot this data, I get 5 series with each 2 values in my plot. What I would like is 2 `Series` with each 5 points in the plot (displaying the histogram). This corresponds to pressing the *"Switch Row/Column"* button in Excel. Unfortunately it is not possible to manually press this button for each chartsheet as there are a lot of them.

How could I achieve this effect within python?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have made a simplified version of my code. It uses the same table as the one shown above.
I realize using MultiIndex is not required in this case, in my full code however, it is required.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart, Reference
   
excel_file = 'test.xlsx'
# create and write data
excel_tests_data = [[0, 1, 5, 2, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 7, 2, 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(excel_tests_data)
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('bin '+str(i), ) for i in range(6)])
df.to_excel(excel_file, startrow=0, sheet_name='test') 
# open workbook
workbook = load_workbook(excel_file)
worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0]
# create chartsheet
chartsheet = workbook.create_chartsheet()
chartsheet.title = "Testsheet"
chart = LineChart()
data = Reference(worksheet, 
                    min_col = 2,
                    min_row = 3,
                    max_row = 4,
                    max_col = 7)
chart.title = "test"
chart.add_data(data)
chartsheet.add_chart(chart)
# save and close workbook
workbook.save(excel_file)
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to the [Switch Row/Column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/change-how-rows-and-columns-of-data-are-plotted-in-a-chart-2be5cea4-715a-4637-9a67-73b99c8dc5e7) button, you can simply *turn-on* the `from_rows` parameter.

```
chart.add_data(data)

chart.add_data(data, from_rows=True)
```

Output (`text.xlsx`):

[image]